# How do I pass a certain data onClick in React in this situation

Tags: reactjs

Basically I have a loop that runs through "ScannedCrops" and each scannedcrop renders with a button which says "View More". I want to pass the id (Which is stored in ScannedCrop._id) and console.log that onClick.

This is the loop

```
<div className={styles.scannedCropsGrid}> 
        {
          scannedCrops.map(ScannedCrop => {
            return <div>
            <div className={styles.center}>
            <div className={styles.scannedCropsContent}>
              <img src={ScannedCrop.image} alt="/" />

              <div className={`${ScannedCrop.healthyBoolean ? styles.healthyPlant : styles.notHealthy}`}>
                {
                  <p>{ScannedCrop.healthyBoolean ? "Healthy" : "Not Healthy"}</p>
                }
              </div>

              <div className={styles.healthDesc}>
                <p>{ScannedCrop.healthyBoolean ? "No Disease" : ScannedCrop.diseaseName}</p>
                <p>||</p>
                <p>{ScannedCrop.dateTime}</p>
              </div>

              <div className={styles.center}>
                <button className={styles.viewMoreBtn}>
                  More Info
                </button>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          })
        }
        </div>
```

This is the onClick function in the same component.

```
const getId = () => {

}
```

What I want to do is that onClick I want to get the ScannedCrop._id and console.log it. I am kind of a beginner at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you want to add a 'key' attribute to the parent  in your map function. This can be either `index` or the `ScannedCrop._id`  (if the later is always unique).

So it'll look like this:

```
...
 {scannedCrops.map((ScannedCrop, index) => {
            return <div key={index (or ScannedCrop._id if unique)} >
...
```

Lastly to answer your question, you first need to define your handler function and then pass it on to your button element inside the `OnClick` event. It should end up looking like this:

```
//it is a common practice to name your functions 
//'handleClick', 'handleOnView' and so on. You can name it
//whatever you want

const handleGetId = (id) => console.log(id)

...
          <div className={styles.center}>
                <button 
                  onClick={() => handleGetId(ScannedCrop._id)} 
                  className={styles.viewMoreBtn}>
                  More Info
                </button>
              </div>
...
```

Hope that answers your question!